# Paperclip + Heroku + S3 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

I followed [this tutorial](http://webtempest.com/how-to-allow-image-uploads-in-rails-on-heroku/) to set up Paperclip with s3 on heroku. And it works fine! 
But now i moved to a new project, and i tried to replicate the steps i made with the first to make image uploads working. But i'm not able to, and this is driving me crazy! Please help me with this problem... i've lost hours and hours. :-/

This is what is happening:
I create an activity choosing a photo, and i think the upload doesn't even start (it's too fast!). No error is called, and the "photo" attribute of my activity is `/photos/original/missing.png`

Here's my model file:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :infos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :links, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :infos

  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles =>{
      :thumb  => "80x60#",
      :medium => "160x120#",
      :large => "320x240#",
      :home => "320x370#"
    },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => ":attachment/activities/:id/:style.:extension",
    :bucket => 'andrea'

end
```

my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"
gem 'aws-s3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

and my s3.yml (with the full keys in the place of "..."):

```
development:
  bucket: andrea
  access_key_id: AKIAII...
  secret_access_key: vM977oy6W2TIbArCG9...

test:
  bucket: andrea
  access_key_id: AKIAII...
  secret_access_key: vM977oy6W2TIbArCG9...

production:
  bucket: andrea
  access_key_id: AKIAII...
  secret_access_key: vM977oy6W2TIbArCG9...
```

Here's the Log:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: infos_attributes
  [1m[36mAREL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "activities" ("photo", "created_at", "updated_at", "home", "photo_file_name", "photo_content_type", "photo_file_size", "photo_updated_at", "name") VALUES (NULL, '2011-04-20 13:27:57.428869', '2011-04-20 13:27:57.428869', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)[0m
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/activities/15
Completed 302 Found in 45ms


Started GET "/activities/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-20 15:27:57 +0200
  Processing by ActivitiesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}
  [1m[35mActivity Load (0.9ms)[0m  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = 15 LIMIT 1
Rendered activities/show.html.erb within layouts/application (13.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 17.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)


Started GET "/photos/large/missing.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-20 15:27:57 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/photos/large/missing.png"):
```

If you need more informations let me know!

Oh, i've tried with `heroku restart`, but nothing changed.

Comment: did you run the paperclip generator or manually add the necessary fields for the attachment?

Comment: i did add them manually. What is the command to do that automatically?

Comment: It is `rails g paperclip activity photo` but it is fine to add manually, just making sure they existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh yeah!!

Finally i caught it: I need to change my `_form.html.erb`, from

```
<%= form_for @activity do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for @activity, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: In the next version of Rails (3.1), multiparts are automatically added, if there are any file-fields. :)